# MobileFirst 8 application breaks when started from APK

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst

When I build Ionicv1 application for MobileFirst 8 and run it on Android 4.4.2 it gives me this error:

`01-26 10:03:32.615 17270-17270/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.ionicframework.plutal594637, PID: 17270
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.ibm.MFPApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to extract the trust manager on a.a.f.a@41cadd88, sslSocketFactory is class com.worklight.wlclient.f
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4544)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1381)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to extract the trust manager on a.a.f.a@41cadd88, sslSocketFactory is class com.worklight.wlclient.f
                                                       at a.v$a.a(SourceFile:599)
                                                       at com.worklight.wlclient.c.<init>(SourceFile:76)
                                                       at com.worklight.wlclient.c.a(SourceFile:246)
                                                       at com.worklight.wlclient.a.f.a(SourceFile:181)
                                                       at com.worklight.common.a.a(SourceFile:545)
                                                       at com.worklight.androidgap.b.a.<init>(SourceFile:54)
                                                       at com.worklight.androidgap.b.a.a(SourceFile:85)
                                                       at com.ibm.MFPApplication.onCreate(SourceFile:21)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4541)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1381) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

It works normally when i start it for debugging (`ionic run android`) but not when i run it from builded APK.

Comment: Is your application uses Crosswalk plugin ??

Comment: No, it doesn't. I don't know if Ionic puts one automatically

Comment: You can check by running command `ionic plugin list` or `ionic cordova plugin list`

Comment: No, i don t see it.

Comment: Do you see this issue only in Android 4.4 ? do you see  same issue in above Android 5 ?

Comment: This only happens on Android 4.4 and only when i put builded application on tablet. When i run it for debugging, it works normaly. On Android 5 and beyond, it works normally in both ways.

Comment: check if proguard-project.txt file of your project  is  according to this blog
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/09/19/mfp-80-obfuscating-android-code-with-proguard/#enabling-proguard-and-obfuscating-the-apk

Especially check this 
-keepclassmembers class * implements javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory {
   private  javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory delegate;
}

Comment: @MarkoMladenovic were you able run apk with my above suggestion.Or how do you able resolve it ?

Comment: yes, but it did the same thing. So i removed android platform and uninstalled cordova, and then reinstalled cordova 6.2 version and re added android platform version 4.4 . That's the only way it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is too late, but in case you still need it... I had the same problem and @manjunath kallannavar give me the solution...

First at all, you need to use the Android ProGuard tool to obfuscate you app.

More info:

- [Obfuscating Android code using Proguard in MobileFirst Foundation 8.0](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/09/19/mfp-80-obfuscating-android-code-with-proguard/)
- [Reduce your code and your resources](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code)

But, for this specific issue, you need to add the following line:

```
-keepclassmembers class * implements javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory {
   private  javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory delegate;
}
```